# Installing ATI FireGL ubuntu server

Tags: 14.04

i have got fireGL v7600 tried to install but nothing working for me, when i goto interface its freezing maybe due to graphics card not installed.

i have read somewhere my driver in following package, but no idea how to install them

xserver-xorg-video-radeonhd

thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)

Comment: @AizuddinZali the problem is that i am unable to operate through the interface, when i login its just freezing unable to anything

Comment: this has to be done through terminal

Comment: then this should help [Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD)

Comment: check the link.

Comment: how to install from following link ... http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man4/radeonhd.4.html

Comment: did you see my posted link? did you try? if you posted your own, then try to install it by yourself.

Comment: yes tried and i tried following command, sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade


as i told you i am unable to stick on user interface, everything should be done through terminal

Comment: please put some effor in reading link i have posted. `3.1. Installing via the command line`.

Comment: @AizuddinZali the link u posted doesnt have 3.1. Installing via the command line??? can u check your link again thx

Comment: Check the link on "Guide". Not the first one, look carefully..